# Using with_scope on a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model with some scopes defined on it:

```
class Alarm < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :open_alarms, where("state != ?", AlarmStates::STATELIST[-1])
  scope :new_alarms, where('state is null')
  scope :site_alarms, lambda{ |site| where(:mac_address => site.mac_address)}
  #etc
end
```

These scopes are all Relation objects, so I should be able to chain them in a with_scope call. But I can't get it all to work. I have been trying something along the lines of

```
Alarm.with_scope(:find => Alarm.open_alarms){all}
```

which, AFAIK, should apply the Relation Alarm .open_alarms onto the find, and then effectively find all alarms matching the open_alarms scope. But I get an 'unidentifed variable or method "all" for Main:Object' error when I try this. I have tried a whole series of variants, but nothing seems to get there.

Where I am trying to get to is being able to chain a series of scopes, then apply pagination so I can output pages of alarms.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@alarms = Alarm.open_alarms.page(params[:page])

@alarms = Alarm.open_alarms.site_alarms("http://sample.me").page(params[:page])

(Using gem will_paginate or kaminari).

You seem to be using pre 3.2 code to do your query.